# React -JS timer is not updating when i change the arrow function to simple function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have been playing around with React Example which is on its official website:

My problem is little bit tricky:

I have the clock `Component` which renders current time to screen using

```
 new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
```

**Code**: This code works fine

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Clock extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {date: new Date()};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),                    //problematic line
      1000
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState({
      date: new Date()
    });
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }
}



function Root() {
  const element = <Clock />
  ReactDOM.render(
    element,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
}

export default Root;
```

**Problem**
But problem is that when i change the `() => this.tick()` into `this.tick()` or `this.tick` the timer runs only first time, and does not run continuously. I am very confusing in this case:

Can any body tell me what is the difference in between `() => this.tick()` and `this.tick()` in this case or why the timer is not updating when i change this `() => this.tick()` into `this.tick()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look up function setInterval, you will notice that the first argument(firstArg) has to be a function that returns another function and the second argument(secondArg) must be a number or an array of numbers that represents delay you want to repeat the function given as first argument.

```
setInterval(firstArg, secondArg) // typeof firstArg must be a function that returns something
```

In your case, you just pass 'this.tick()' or 'this.tick' that returns nothing. Since this.tick() returns nothing, setInterval can't keep updating 'date' state.

If you change tick() to

```
tick() {
  return () => this.setState({ //returns anonymous function
    date: new Date()
  });
}
```

or

```
tick = () => () => {
  this.setState({
    date: new Date()
  });
}
```

You can achieve this.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.timerID = setInterval(
    this.tick()
    1000
  );
}
```

Comment: You answer was great this helps me to understand the concept clearly.

Comment: Thank you. Glad my answer helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

The only difference which affects the working of this code is that,

`() => this.tick()` is a function where as

`this.tick()` is a function call statement.

So the set timer's first parameter should be a function which gets called after the time interval. When you change it to this.tick(), then the setTimeout will try to execute this.tick()() which will not work. This works the first time when the setTimeout function is getting initialised the parameter(which is a function) is called instead of being initialised.

Comment: but if i  convert 
() => this.tick() to this.tick then it also not work then what is the reason behind this because this.tick is the reference to function?  is i am right?

Answer (score 0):

It is how [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) in JavaScript works.

```
const object1 = {
  method(){
    setTimeout(function () { console.log(this) })
  }
}

const object2 = {
  method(){
    setTimeout(() => { console.log(this) })
  }
}

// the same as
var object3 = {
  method: function method() {
    var _this = this;

    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(_this);
    });
  }
};

object1.method(); // window
object2.method(); // object2
object3.method(); // object3
```